# Proving $\text{ZFC}$ to be Consistent and Independence Proofs

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, independence, axioms

I was looking over the proofs we use to show that $\text{CH}$ is independent to $\text{ZFC}$.  The methods used have to be higher than $\text{ZFC}$, otherwise the proof could be formalized in $\text{ZFC}$ and would show that $\text{ZFC + CH}\vdash \text{Cons(ZFC + CH)}$, thus showing that $\text{ZFC + CH}$ is inconsistent by Gödel's incompleteness theorem.

I was wondering, if we are able to use such proofs for the independence of these formulas (and we accept them as true, despite them being above finitary reasoning), could we ever be able to show that $\text{ZFC}$ is consistent using the same level or reasoning? Would we accept this as a strong argument?  Do any mathematicians object to the independence proofs because they can't be finitary?  Do we care about proving $\text{ZFC}$ consistent or do we just assume it is?

Comment: Formally speaking, those methods show, in ZFC, that Con(ZFC) implies Con(ZFC+CH) or something like that. If by using the same reasoning to show consistency of ZFC you mean proving that Con(ZFC) implies Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)), then if we could do that, it would imply ZFC+Con(ZFC) is inconsistent by Godel.

Comment: (also, in the first sentence I assume you mean proving AC is independent of ZF. AC is an axiom of ZFC so is not independent of it)

Comment: You're right i should specify that AC is independent of ZF

Comment: @Wojowu what I'm essentially saying is, could we construct a prove of consistency using the nonfinitary reasoning and still have it be compelling.

Comment: The independence proofs *are* finitary, though (or can be made finitary, anyway, depending on the method used). You are confusing relative consistency proofs with absolute consistency proofs.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I thought model theory and forcing weren't finitary.   For example, in model theory, the universal quantifier is a statement about an infinite set.

Comment: @BENG Depends on how forcing is formulated. The usual approach certainly isn't (and it's also suboptimal in the sense that it shows if a *transitive* model of ZFC exists then one of ZFC+X exists, rather than just a model). But there are ways of turning a standard forcing argument into a finitary proof of Con(ZFC) -> Con(ZFC+X). And other formulations (Boolean-valued models, forcing-relation-only) are more directly syntactic.

Comment: ok cool thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The consistency proofs are indeed "$\sf\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)\to\operatorname{Con}(ZFC+CH)\land\operatorname{Con}(ZFC+\lnot CH)$", and while we can in fact formalise these proofs *in $\sf ZFC$ itself*, and indeed it is *far more convenient for us to do that*, we can actually formalise them in weak theories like $\sf PRA$.

Now, your question is ultimately kind of meaningless, since we are not proving $\sf ZFC\vdash\operatorname{Con}(ZFC+CH)$, but rather an implication. But it is true that $\sf ZFC$ proves that every of its finite fragments is consistent. You can conclude from this that if $\sf ZFC$ is indeed consistent, then any model of $\sf ZFC+\lnot\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$ must contain non-standard integers, since no "real axioms" can lead to a proof of contradiction which has a "really finite length" using "real inference rules" (in other words, any proof that can be coded by a real finite integer cannot be a proof that $0=1$ from $\sf ZFC$).

You can use this as a philosophical argument in favour of $\sf ZFC$, but of course there is a circularity to it. It only works if you assume that $\sf ZFC$ is already consistent, otherwise the whole point is moot. Inconsistent theories prove everything anyway.